# Comparing O((logn) ^ const) with O(n)

Tags: math, big-o

I did some computation and found out that if const = 2, then the derivative of the n in the infinity would be 1, and the derivative of the (logn) ^ 2 would be 2logn/n, which is tend to be 0, thus it seems O(n) /O((logn)^2) should be divergent when n is going to infinity, but what if const > 2?

Comment: You can use your result for log² n to figure out what log² n/n approaches, then that result for log³ n/n, and so on…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looking at the derivative, consider rewriting each expression in terms of the same base. Notice, for example, that for any logarithm base b that

> n = b<sup>log<sub>b</sub> n</sup>,

so in particular

> n = (log n)<sup>log<sub>(log n)</sub> n</sup>

which can be rewritten using properties of logarithms as

> n = (log n)<sup>log n / log log n</sup>

Your question asks how (log n)<sup>k</sup> compares against n. This means that we're comparing (log n)<sup>k</sup> against (log n)<sup>log n / log log n</sup>. This should make clearer that no constant k will ever cause (log n)<sup>k</sup> to exceed n, since the term log n / log log n will eventually exceed k for any fixed constant k.